# Is it safe to typecast unsigned short to wchar_t and vise versa?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-6

Hello
I am migrating project from Visual studio 6.0 to Visual Studio 2005.

The problem i am facing is ths ... in VS 6.0 `wchar_t` was simply typecast of `unsigned short` but in VS2005 `wchar_t` is built in data type.

In project previous programmers have used wchar_t and unsigned short intechangibally. 
But in Vs 2005 it showing errors like cannot convert from `wchar_t` to `unsigned short` and vise versa.

So my question is can we safely cast `wchar_t` to `unsigned short` and vise versa or we need use functions like mbstowcs and wcstombs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /Zc:wchar_t- (or its equivalent in the project settings dialog) to turn off the wchar_t-as-native-type feature in VS 2005:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: : Thanks for your comment ... I applied :/Zc:wchar_t and now VS 2005 not giving any error

Answer (score 1):

Changing option Treat wchar_t as native type to NO worked for me :). VC++ 2010 express.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be fine but, if it were me, I'd do a search and replace and change references to Unicode characters to `wchar_t`. For starters, you might just make your code work with future changes to the libraries. It would also make your code easier to read.

Unless I'm missing something, `mbstowcs` and `wcstombs` have nothing to do with this. They are for converting between Unicode and multiple. It sounds like all your stuff is Unicode.